# Regexp Escape method

Tags: ruby

How can I escape the single quote using Regexp.escape() method in ruby?
input="university's"
output="university\'s"
can i get like this?

Comment: Why, what for? Show us some code and elaborate on the reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

No, the purpose of that method is to escape the characters that have special meaning in regular expressions (like "(", "[", "$"). What you probably want is [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186).